# Missing Email Header after export to mht or eml with Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

i'm trying to export a email as mht or eml.
The export is working but the content is incomplete.

[image: Email Sample]

The Export only contains the content of the green box.
The Content from the red box is missing (sender, recipient, subject, sent).

```
    string emlFileName = @"C:\export\email.eml";
    string mhtFileName = @"C:\export\email.mht";

    // Save as .eml.
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(emlFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length);
    }

    // Save as .mht.
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(mhtFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length);
    }
```

Comment: "MIME RFCs do not mandate that headers be maintained after a message has been stored." > see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Perhaps this is because you asked for the mime content, not the whole email? which will only handle the email content

Comment: It should work okay you may want to post the MimeContent you actual do see. The Exchange Store should do an on the fly conversion from the Native format to MIME so it maybe your server isn't patched and there was a store bug that has been fixed so I would check your server patch level as well.